# How to transfer 15 to 1,2,4,8 in php

Tags: php, binary

Just like this:

```
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 1,2
5 = 1,4
6 = 2,4
7 = 1,2,4
9 = 1,8
15 = 1,2,4,8
31 = 1,2,4,8,16
```

It seems need some binary function.

Comment: really simple solution! every number has all set bits

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use decbin to make the number binary, then use an array as the lookup to what number in binary it is.
I use array_intersect to find the "true" values and use array_intersect_key to match them in the $arr. 
This is a non looping solution that may or may not be faster.

```
$arr= [16,8,4,2,1];
$number = 13;
$bin = str_split(str_pad(decbin($number),count($arr),"0",STR_PAD_LEFT));

Echo implode(",", array_intersect_key($arr,array_intersect($bin, ["1"])));
```

https://3v4l.org/t9QQc

If the order is important then you need to sort it prior to output.

```
$nums = array_intersect_key($arr,array_intersect($bin, ["1"]));
sort($nums);
Echo implode(",", $nums);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this!

```
function split($n) {
    $n |= 0;
    $pad = 0;
    $arr = array();
    while ($n) {
        if ($n & 1) array_push($arr, 1 << $pad);
        $pad++;
        $n >>= 1;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```